# Inserting XMLEvent using Location object

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, stax

Is there a way to write `XMLEvent` using `XMLEventWriter` at the location of another `XMLEvent` read using `XMLEventReader`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot edit an XML file in-place using `XMLReader`. You *can* copy the entire XML to an output file (or stream) by sending all events from an `XMLReader` directly to an `XMLWriter`. You can then create your own `XMLEvent`s on the fly and feed them to the `XMLWriter` at the appropriate time and they will show up in the new document.

Comment: Yes. It would require lot of effort to maintain concurrency.

Comment: I don't understand your remark. There's no reason to complicate things with concurrency, only a single thread can pull events from an `XMLReader` and only a single thread can write events to an `XMLWriter`. This can be the same thread. All you have to do with your `EventListener` in between is forward each event from the reader to the writer, but inspect each event to detect the desired insert location. At that point you feed a handmade `XMLEvent` to the writer then resume forwarding input from the reader. All in one thread.